# The control property changes the immediate application (DesignSurface)

Tags: propertygrid

I have created DesignSurface. However, if I change the properties of the control, for example, the Size property.

I stretched Form, so the Size attribute of PropertyGrid should also be changed in time. But I've been looking at Google and MSDN for a long time and haven't found out how to do it. Can you tell me what I should do? Thank you

Part of the code
[image]

You can see that the LOCATION property of this button is not correct. This is because the property has not been updated in time.

[image]

My problem is how to update control properties to propertyGrid in time.
Thank you

Comment: Rather than providing a link to an image of your code, you should add it as text within your question.

Answer (score 0):

oh,I have solved my problem by myself. The code reads as follows. Mainly the application of IComponentChangeService. Thanks MSDN. Too long.

IComponentChangeService ccs = (IComponentChangeService)host.GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));

```
        ccs.ComponentChanged += new ComponentChangedEventHandler(OnComponentChanged);
```

/* This method handles the OnComponentChanged event to display a notification. */
        private void OnComponentChanged(object sender, ComponentChangedEventArgs ce)
        {
            if (ce.Component != null && ((IComponent)ce.Component).Site != null && ce.Member != null)
                Debug.WriteLine("The " + ce.Member.Name + " member of the " + ((IComponent)ce.Component).Site.Name + " component has been changed.");

```
    }
```